# C# String Comparison?

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Using == or Equals for string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968787/using-or-equals-for-string-comparison)
>   [Are string.Equals() and == operator really same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same)

I learned Java first and one of the few absolutes is that you never use == to compare if two strings are equal, instead there's the equals method. So when I landed in C# years ago and noticed that objects still had an Equals method, I assumed the rule still applied.

Now I'm going through an ex-coworker's code and I'm finding snippets like this everywhere:

```
if (s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("_")) == "GBCI") {...}
```

If I recall correctly, == will compare the address between those two results and since the first half is returned by a function, this will fail because the result won't be the same address as the constant on the right.

Am I holding on to old Java habits? Or is it a good thing that my coworker isn't around any more?

P.S. Regardless your answer to comparing strings, I do realize the above would be better stated as `s.BeginsWith("GBCI")`, but that's something else entirely.

Comment: Regarding the PS.    it would be if (s.BeginsWith("GBCI_") == true).   And that is a lot better.

Comment: Or even `if (s.BeginsWith("GBCI_"))`

Comment: I prefer BoltClock's way. If it returns a bool, why compare that to a bool in order to get another bool? The line 'x == true' will return exactly the same thing as simply 'x' (saying that x is a bool of course)

Comment: Oh, I see what you changed, mostly the _ involved in the constant string. I certainly see why you think that it should be there, but what you didn't know (and I don't chide you for it) is that the underscore doesn't matter. The string in question either begins with GBCI or CSB, just had to figure out which one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C#, `==` comparison for strings compares their values instead of their references. See [this section of the C# spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664728%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for details.

So using it like that works fine; your coworker was sane and sober.

Answer (score 0):

As another note, look at [this](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/StringComparison.aspx) link.

You can use `==` however `compareTo` is unique in that it will return an integer based on how the strings differ (or don't differ).